# Model (regression) stepwise function (time-varying variable) for several observations

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, time-varying-covariate

For each observation, we have a plot like this: [image]

where the x-axis is the time and the y-axis is the value of interest. For each observation, the time of the jumps can be different, as well as the height of the jumps.
However, we have several covariates that can (hopefully) explain both the time and the height of a jump.

For example, we could have that the covariate age has an influence on the size of the steps: observations that coincide with young people, will have a plot with large jumps

Do you have some suggestions of models that we can use for such a situation?